# On Ubuntu, after connecting to smb://pcname, where is the folder under "/"?

Tags: ubuntu

On Ubuntu, after connecting to `smb://<PC NAME>`, where is the folder under `/`?

that is, how to bash shell to `cd` to that share?

on Mac OS X, it is some where in `/Volumes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: it works!  can it be under some where more... like /mnt or /dev ?

Comment: Only if you mount it at the command line as root using `mount`.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out for yourself by running `mount` with no arguments; it will list all the mount points on your system.